# How to get next set of data on select top

Tags: mysql, sql

I loaded the result set with top 10 rows as follows.

```
SELECT * FROM Persons LIMIT 10;
```

Now how to select next 10 rows.? Like what in google search results can be toggled between search results.
Pardon if question sounds silly because i didn't found any relevant answer on google.

Comment: This is actually just MySQL you're concerned with, not PostgreSQL, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `OFFSET` + `LIMIT` to do this

```
   SELECT * FROM Persons
   ORDER BY somecol 
   OFFSET 10 LIMIT 10 -- LIMIT 10 OFFSET 10
```

For `Mysql`

```
   SELECT * FROM Persons
   ORDER BY somecol 
   LIMIT 10 OFFSET 10 --LIMIT 10,10
```

**Note:** Make sure you add `Order by` to get meaningful results

Comment: Should this not rather be `LIMIT 10 OFFSET 10`?

Comment: @VR46 . Thank you. Dynamically change the LIMIT and OFFSET. Is that what makes it?

Comment: No, it is not dynamic. You have to increase the number behind `OFFSET` for each new "page" that you want to get from the database. Edit: oh, I might have misread you there. If you already meant that this is what you have to do, then: yes. :) sorry!

Answer (score 2):

You can give the LIMIT clause a starting point, like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Persons LIMIT 50, 10;
```

This would mean the offset is 50 (it skips the first 50 rows), and the next 10 rows are selected. See also in the manual: [MySQL SELECT Syntax.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html)